# Error "Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token " returned when using selenium.setSpeed()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I included `selenium.setSpeed("2000");` inside my void main i got the syntax error "selenium cannot be resolved"

When I placed it outside my void main and inside my class I got the error :

```
"Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token ",", < expected - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName"
```

Please do help me resolve this issue.

Comment: share your code please ? and tag language also..

Comment: public String getCurrentDay (){
        //Create a Calendar Object
  selenium.setSpeed("2000");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
 
        //Get Current Day as a number
       int todayInt = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("Today Int: " + todayInt +"\n");
 
        //Integer to String Conversion
        String todayStr = Integer.toString(todayInt);
        System.out.println("Today Str: " + todayStr + "\n");
 
        return todayStr;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ancient versions of *Selenium* of-coarse had a method as **`setSpeed()`** but this method had been deprecated long back. `setSpeed()` was used to control the speed of each step of your *Automation Script*. As the purpose of *Automated Testing* is to reduce the *Validation Time* so setting the speed of each line of your script execution through `setSpeed()` was contradictory. Hence `setSpeed()` was deprecated.

Incase you want to wait for a certain condition you can use either [**Implicit Wait**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) or [**Explicit Wait**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) i.e. [**WebDriverWait**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) Class in-conjunction with [**ExpectedConditions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Comment: Oh Ok. THank you... I was under the assumption that setSpeed was still under use.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner input will not work if you try to use it at the beginning of a class. It will show syntax errors like this.
(Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration)
The solution is: You have to use Scanner input within the main method().